# Can I force coefficients between 0-1 in LinearRegression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `LinearRegression` from `sklearn.linear_model`. Can I force the coefficients between 0 and 1? Also, can I give priority to solutions involving only binary coefficients? (Assume such a solution exists!)

From https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html, I only know how to force positive coefficients using the `positive=True` parameter, but coefficients reach values above 1:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression(positive=True, fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y)
```

Alternatively, can you suggest a different model for this?

EDIT:
As I understand, the command `reg.coef_` shows the coefficients that were found to fit the data best. Can I force the algorithm to only look for solutions with coefficients in the range of 0-1 (or if possible binary)? E.g., `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` allows to set `bounds` (possible ranges) for each variable.

Comment: what do you mean by `force the coefficients`? To hide them from the summary output?

Comment: I mean to limit the possible range of coefficients. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sklearn `LinearRegression()` is a wrapper for `scipy.linalg.lstsq()`. It does not implement a constrained version as far as I know, but you can try `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear()`:

```
from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear   
res = lsq_linear(X, y, bounds=(0, 1))
# Get coefficients:
print(res.x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this runs endlessly for me. I don't think the wrapper can cause such a difference in speed, so it must be the constraint. Maybe there is a faster solution.

Comment: Did you try `method='bvls'` as well?

Comment: Now I did. Speed increase x1000 at least. Awesome!